# Miscommunication with new employer regarding Notice Period

Tags: human-resources, job-change, notice-period

I have job offer from europe but the company is delaying the process of obtaining my work permit. I am already done serving my notice period in my current organization in India. But i think there is some miscommunication as the HR from the new company told me that they are working on my WP and once done then I can resign from my current organization and join them.

I was relieved from my current job in July and was suppose to join the new company in December.

Should I convey this to the HR, because :

1. They might be delaying thinking I already have a job which I don't !
2. If I lie and say that I am still working then last working day in the relieving letter is july. Can that cause any issue ?

Any help as to what should I do would be highly appreciated !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You absolutely should tell the HR representative at your new company the situation.  If they believe you are still working, they might not be in a particular rush to get things finalized for your work permit.  Hopefully, they can expedite the process.

Never lie to a potential employer.  Although it probably wouldnt hurt you if they found out, at the very least you lose some credibility at best.  At worst, they do not hire you, or have a reason to fire you.  There is nothing to be gained by lying.

Leaving a job before you have everything in order to start your new job is a bad idea in general.  Your work permit might be held up in red tape for an unknown amount of time.  What if it takes an additional few weeks to months to be approved?  How do you support yourself?  Additionally, what happens if it is denied for some reason?  Until all the paperwork is set for you to legally start working, leaving the job you have is a bad idea.

Comment: Yeah even I was thinking the same. Thanks anyways :)